# A spacious charade

Tags: riddle, word

For my first puzzle here, something short and simple. Well, short.

> My first is a space.
>
> My second leads to a space.
>
> My whole is in space.
>
> What am I?

Hint 1:

> The answer is a single word.

Hint 2:

> The answer is fictional.

Hint 3:

> The first is something you can(not) see, the second is something you can(not) hold, and the whole is somewhere you can(not) go.

Comment: Is it a single word or multiple words?

Comment: I have added two hints.

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> a pace?

Reasoning:

> The first thing in a pace is a single step, which is a 'space'. The second step leads to yet another space. The whole of 'pace' is located in the word 'space'.

Comment: Not bad, but not right. I do like the wordplay in your explanation for the third line.

Answer (score 1):

Is it...

> a black hole?

My first is a space.

> Empty space is black. (Not sure about this one...)

My second leads to a space.

> When things fall out of a hole, the container becomes empty.

My whole is in space.

> Black holes are certainly in space!

Comment: Yeah, if that was my intended answer I would have worded the first line differently. But thanks for the attempt!

Answer (score 1):

I am

> a Klein bottle.  My outsides are in.  My hole is in space.  My insides are out.
>
>  I'm not sure if I'm coming or going... but I'm a real physical object in 3D space.
>
>  [image: Klein Bottle]

Comment: nice piccy - where did you get it?

Comment: Not the right answer, but I am a fan of Klein bottles. This particular riddle is more about wordplay than mathplay.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> A Stargate? It is a space, and leads to another space, and generally speaking, anything that exists, exists in space. It is one word, and fictional.

Also consider:

> Elysium? Fictional, one word, is a space, leading to spaces(places) within it, and is in space.

Or even better:

> Bifröst. A bridge, too is a space, right?

Comment: Your first guess is closer than any other guess so far.